# get v4.app.FragmentManager from Flutter Plugin

Tags: android, flutter

i try to get FragmentManager in my android flutter plugin. In my case i need v4.app.FragmentManager.

but in PluginRegistry Registrar. i just get app.FragmentManager from Registrar.activity().fragmentManager

Since i use FlutterFragmentActivity which extend v4.app.FragmentActivity, you can see the code in [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/app/FlutterFragmentActivity.java).

So i think it's possible to get v4.app.FragmentManager().
anyone have idea how to reach that ?

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` might return null, if the class it's called from is not attached to a context. Consider using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead

Comment: Actually... Where and with what object i can call getSupportFragmentManager() in flutter plugin android.

i try to call using Registrar object. Registrar just present activity with app.Activity not v4.app.Activity.  I try to cast into Application it seems not work

Comment: Cross-link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25060

Comment: yah its me in github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally, i solve this problem with simple fact:

First, `Registrar.activity` is `app.activity` which is if you want to get fragment manager you only get `app.FragmentManager`. So we can't call `getSupportFragmentManager()` function to get `v4.app.FragmentManager`.

Second, `FlutterActivity` / `FLutterFragmentActivity` is extending `v4.app.Activity` / `v4.app.FragmentActivity` so we can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in this case.

So simply in Flutter Android plugin I just declare `Activity` / `FragmentActivity` equals with what `MainActivity` extended like. After that I can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to get `v4.app.FragmentManager`. the code like below :

```
v4.app.Activity act = (Activity)vRegistrar.activity();
v4.app.FragmentManager = act.getSupportFragmentManger();
```

Hope it's helpful. Thanks...

Comment: i tried this and it doesn't work `override fun getSupportFragmentManager(): FragmentManager {
    val act = registrar!!.activity() as Activity
    return act.getSupportFragmentManager()
  }`

Comment: i can get the context from registar just fine, but i can't get the support fragment manager for some reason

Comment: What are you using the FragmentManager for in the plugin? I am trying to add a Fragment to my flutter app but it's not quite working. I return the View by calling onCreateView() on my Fragment. Do you have another way? Would be a great help.