# Trying to build a Flutter Plugin that calls getSupportFragmentManager() in Android

Tags: android, flutter

Hello I am building a new Flutter plugin that works with an SDK

the SDK on the Android side requires that I call getSupportFragmentManager()

I have tried to call this on the "registrar" Activity in my Android plugin class but it keeps giving me an error

"Unresolved reference: getSupportFragmentManager"

Here is my code: I'm calling getSupportFragmentManager() at the bottom

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get v4.app.FragmentManager from Flutter Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652167/get-v4-app-fragmentmanager-from-flutter-plugin)

Comment: i saw that and tried ```override fun getSupportFragmentManager(): FragmentManager {
    val act = registrar!!.activity() as Activity
    return act.getSupportFragmentManager()
  }```

Comment: but this didn't work

Comment: still getting `Unresolved reference: getSupportFragmentManager`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing regular `Activity` class:

```
import android.app.Activity
```

To access `SupportFragmentManager` you need `FragmentActivity`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Then you can do

```
val act = registrar.activity() as FragmentActivity
return act.supportFragmentManager
```

---

Note that you also need to add *android.support.v4* dependency in `android/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

and inherit `MainActivity` from `FlutterFragmentActivity` instead of `FlutterActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this

```
override fun getSupportFragmentManager(): FragmentManager {
    val act = registrar!!.activity() as FragmentActivity
    return act.getSupportFragmentManager()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

val activity = ((context as MutableContextWrapper).baseContext) as MainActivity

val fragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).